# Why doesn't operator exist in this condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the following query:

```
 with tbl as (
 select 1 as id, 'abc' as code union all
 select 2, '2'
)
 select id, code, id+'1' from tbl

-- id   code    ?column?
-- 1    abc 2
-- 2    2   3
```

I can add a number plus a string-encoded number. However, this exact same thing is forbidden when between two columns, which seems very inconsistent to me:

```
 with tbl as (
 select 1 as id, 'abc' as code union all
 select 2, '2'
)
 select id, code, id+code from tbl
```

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer + text

Why does it allow it in one case and not the other? By comparison, MySQL allows this in both cases -- of course MySQL is considered loose in what it allows type-wise, but at least it's consistent.

Comment: See [Type Casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS): *4.2.9. Type Casts A cast applied to an unadorned string literal represents the initial assignment of a type to a literal constant value, and so it will succeed for any type (if the contents of the string literal are acceptable input syntax for the data type).*  Read the section below the above for explanation of your second case.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks I think that solves it! What do they mean by 'unadorned string literal'? Does that mean without any expression around it? As in: `x="hi"` is ok but `x=("hi")` or `x="hi"||"x"` is not? (tested, and it seems the first one works but not the second, so maybe they mean any 'non-trivial expression').

Comment: Honestly I don't know. My preference is to use an explicit cast when in doubt. Though in this case that is not going to work as the `+` operator will not work for `'abc' + 2`.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/typeconv-oper.html I think first example related operator resolution. In your first example `id+'1'` the '1' is unknown argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the inconsistency in PostgreSQL's behavior when adding a number to a string-encoded number versus adding two columns together is due to the data type coercion rules defined in the SQL standard.

In the first case where you add a number to a string-encoded number (`id+'1'`), PostgreSQL applies implicit type conversion. It recognizes that the `id` column is of integer type and the string `'1'` can be parsed as an integer, so it converts the string to an integer and performs the addition operation successfully.

However, in the second case where you try to add the `id` column to the `code` column (`id+code`), the implicit type conversion rules do not allow automatic conversion between integer and text types. In PostgreSQL, the `+` operator is defined for adding two integers or adding two floating-point numbers, but not for adding an integer and a text value.

While MySQL may allow such operations and perform implicit conversions more liberally, PostgreSQL follows stricter type-checking rules to ensure data integrity and prevent potentially unintended behavior or loss of precision.

If you want to concatenate the `id` and `code` columns as strings, you can explicitly cast the `id` column to text using the `::text` syntax, like this:

```sql
WITH tbl AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'abc' AS code UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2'
)
SELECT id, code, id::text || code FROM tbl;
```

This will convert the `id` column to text and then concatenate it with the `code` column, producing the desired result:

```
 id | code | column
----+------+----------
  1 | abc  | 1abc
  2 | 2    | 22
```

Comment: @amira -- any possible way to link the following text: `due to the data type coercion rules defined in the SQL standard` ? Or is that not public to link.